# change from windows authentication to sql server authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication, windows-authentication

can anyone tell me how to change from windows authentication to SQL server authentication.I have been using this as my connection string

```
"server=.;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Work;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: **Remove** the `Integrated Security=True` (that's what defines Windows auth), and **add** a user id and password `User id=someUserName;password=password` to the connection string - that's it

Comment: the connection that i mentioned above works i wanted to use the connection string that you gave but what is the user id and password because i don't have it like the mentioned in the pic below

Comment: Well, if you want to use SQL Server authentication, then **you must have** a user id and a password to log on to that SQL Server ....

Answer (score 1):

Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Connection Strings But Were Afraid to Ask - [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

The following connectionString format should do the job.

```
connectionString="user id=yourUsername; password=yourPassword;data source=yourServerName;initial catalog=yourDatabaseName;"
```

Comment: i dis't give the userid and password and when i select windows authentication both are blank 
http://postimg.org/image/4qznkkycr